# Traffic lights in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, traffic

I need to do a conditional formatting saying that if the value % is:
between -5% and 5% GREEN LIGHT
between -10% and 10% YELLOW LIGHT
otherwise RED LIGHT

The range where I need to apply the format is in H19:N19

The formulas that give the percentages in each cell are:(+H17-H18)/H18 for cell H19

Comment: Where is your problem? SO is a Q&A site. What you wrote above, is not a question!

Comment: I think you need to show us the code you are working with so it will be clear

Answer (score -1):

This should work its an example I tested it

```
=IF(AND(D2:D10<5%;-5%);"Green Light";IF(AND(D2:D10<10%;-10%);"Yellow Light";"RED LIGHT"))
```